# Where can I find the list of packages for my Debian installation?

Tags: linux, debian

I have the netinstall distro of Debian. During the installation I can choose, for example "web server" or "Desktop environment".

Where can I find list of packages I'm installing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tasksel will tell you this:

http://wiki.debian.org/tasksel

```
# tasksel --task-packages web-server (List the packages that would be installed by that task) 
libapache2-mod-python
apache2-doc
libapache2-mod-php5
libapache2-mod-perl2
apache2-mpm-prefork
analog
```

Comment: # tasksel --task-packages desktop
task-desktop   what I'm doing wrong?